# xpages display the document history

Tags: xpages

In some 'old' lotus notes applications, we created a history of each document: who created the doc, every person which edited it + the respective dates. The code contained several libraries in lotusScript.

For xpages, is there any snippet / sample working example which I could use? I found [this](http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/0/4F5BEA7A4A07C74D86257769004E549C) but I couldn't download any example ...

Answer (score 2):

ValueChangeListeners allow you to capture changes to specific components. I've used them to create audit trails in customer applications before.

Tony McGuckin has an XSnippet for it:
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=server-side-value-change-events-listeners

Declan Lynch covered it in a blog post:
http://www.qtzar.com/using-a-valuechangelistener-to-build-an-audit-trail/

Don McNally has also done a blog post:
http://dmcnally.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/xpages-detecting-and-logging-field.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any pre-done snippet yet.  But this becomes a lot easier in XPages especially if expand into Java.  When I create an application these days I basically convert the document to a Java object.  I don't do this yet but it would be easy to store in the object a Map of all the fields and their current values and then on save, look for differences and then write them out to a log document.

this could be done without java of course.  Create an map object in scope.  Populate it on loading of the document and on save do the compare and write.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong with that project on OpenNTF (don't ever use an ampersand in the name). I'm the original author of that custom control. AFter some digging I found [a direct url to the project here](http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/627601b45e12fbf585256db8005b9d19/6569257991cc17758625778a006dc17b?OpenDocument).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just need to modify it a little. Btw, is there any chance at the Revisions part - to add also, along side the date, the person name which took the respective revision? I know I had to add another computed field... thanks again, hope to see my regard soon.

Comment: Sure, the custom control is open source, so go ahead and build in whatever you need.

Comment: I can't get the date from the Edited by section. The field inside the repeat is returning: @Name("[CN]" , rowAuthors). I do not know how to display the respective day for each edit. Could you explain me how to achieve this?